# Boolean algebra on Logic Circuit

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need help with this function to create a truth table:
F(a, b, c) = a'c' + abc + ac'
Use Boolean laws and theorems to reduce the given function
I need the reduced and original function truth table
From there I will be able to create a logic gate circuit
Thanks

Comment: So ..... do you first need to create a truth-table and derive a simplified exprssion from that?  Or do you need to use boolean algebra laws to simplify? Which is it? Also, if you have to use algebra, what rules do you have available to you?  Do you have adjacency?  Reduction?  Complement?

Comment: Basically I want to apply the Moore"s Law to simplify and than use the original and reduced funtion to create a truth table and with the truth table I can implement the logic gate on multisim

Comment: Moore's Law will likely not help, this is a law about how the number of transistors in a computer changes over time. I would review the basic rules of Boolean Algebra.

Comment: @geometry18 That approach makes little sense: first you want to simplify, and then create a truth-table?  The truth-table will be the same for any two equivalent statements, so any simplifications you do beforehand don't help. Also, the expression you get from a truth-table is typically fairly complex .. certainly more complex than the statement you have at this point. So, I would just stay away from a truth-table completely.

Answer (score 0):

Notice $F(a,b,c) = c'(a'+a) +abc.$ The term $a' + a$ will always be $1$. So we have $F(a,b,c) = c' + abc$. To find the truth table just input all different combinations of $a, b, c$ and write down the respective outputs.